# Can eclipse prevent you from using particular classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

For example,

1. I don't want to use `org.testng.v6.Maps`, (I want `com.google.common.collect.Maps`)
2. I don't want to use `org.hibernate.mapping.List`, (I want `java.util.List` like everyone else!)

Is there a way to tell Eclipse not to suggest these in the autocomplete box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup - I have exactly this problem at work for a few classes too.

Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters.

Answer (score 0):

Re-arrange your dependencies in the library path according to the order you want them to be.

- Right click on project > *Properties*
- *Java Build Path*
- *Order and Export* tab

This should give priority to the dependencies you do prefer. (Although on second thought I am not sure this is reflected in the auto-complete boxes.)